# Implementing Fingerprint Scanning for Web Application on Client-Side

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

We got tasked at my company to conduct research for an implementation on a how to use a fingerprint scanner in our Web Applications. A sample scenario would be when a client uses the web application, he would for instance need to give fingerprint authentication to complete an action. The only restrictions are that we cannot write/use Silverlight or Active X plugins. Thus far, the only thing that I know is that there will need to be a C# service running on the client machine (which the client will install along side the driver of the fingerprint scanner of course) which will communicate with the client side web page. The service will handle the calls from the fingerprint scanner API and has to pass it to the Client Page.

Where do I start looking/reading to implement such as project?

We are working in an ASP.NET MVC With AngularJS Environment.

Comment: What is the point that you're unsure of? Creating the API endpoint in ASP.Net or writing the client application?

Comment: How to code the service and creating the API endpoint in ASP.NET. The service implementation can be vendor specific, i.e. writing a service that would work with Company X's fingerprint scanner.

Comment: I did, but most articles mention the use of Silverlight or Active X. I posted the question because the problem is outside the scope of what I am familiar with. So I'm afraid I might be searching for the wrong question when I google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have a class Fingerprint:

```
public class Fingerprint
{
   public string Value{ get; set; }

   // Other important properties
}
```

In ASP.NET, add a new, empty API controller, i.e.

```
public class FingerprintController : ApiController
{
   [HttpPut]
   public async Task Put(Fingerprint fingerprint){
      // Code for handling the fingerprint here
   }
}
```

you can now call this API i.e. by using the url:

http://example.com/api/Fingerprint

Very easy. You basically define the structure of the values in a class and in your API you can receive them. Note that I made HttpPut attribute above the method with the same name, this is unnecessary, but is nice to be verbose in code :)

Comment: Thank you! This seems to be straightforward enough to build upon :)